# Frobenius elements in number fields.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

There is a concept of Frobenius conjugacy class for an unramified prime. Similarly, can we define for ramified primes by taking the conjugates of inertia cosets?

Comment: Yes but (for a Galois extension) you need to be careful with what properties don't depend on the chosen representative of $ \{ \sigma \in G,\exists P | (p), \forall a \in O_K,\sigma(a) \equiv a^p \bmod P \}$ (the characteristic polynomial stays the same under conjugaison but to make things independent of left multiplication by the intertia group we need to restrict to the [$I_P$-fixed subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin_L-function))

Comment: What do we want to keep independent of left multiplication by the inertia group? @reuns

Comment: $P$ a prime above $(p)$ then we are looking at $Frob_p=\{ g i \phi_P g^{-1},g \in G,i \in I_P\}$ where $I_P = \{ \sigma \in G,\forall a \in O_K, \sigma(a) -a \in P\}$ and $\phi_P$ is some automorphism satisfying $\forall a \in O_K, \phi_P(a) -a^p \in P$.

Comment: should $I_p$ and $\phi_P$ vary over all the primes $P$ above p? @reuns

Comment: $$I_{g(P)} \phi_{g(P)} = gI_P \phi_P g^{-1}$$

Comment: How can I show that the characteristic polynomial of $\rho(\phi_P)|_{V^{I_P}}$ and $\rho(\phi_Q)|_{V^{I_Q}}$ are same for two distinct primes P and Q over p. where $\rho$ is the corresponding representation.@reuns